# HALF of the image is flipped on a curved plane?

Tags: texturing, uv, bezier-curves

I'm a bit of a Blender novice, so be gentle.

I'm trying to create a simple movie screen using a curved plane. I created a 2D plane, applied a simple 90' curve, and UVMapped a single png for the texture.

When I first applied the UVMap, I noticed my texture started displaying from the center of my plane outwards to the right and was both backwards & upside-down. Rotating the UVMap 180' moved the left side of my image to the left side of my object and displaying properly, but now the right HALF is rotated 180' starting from the center of my plane.

WTH? How do I fix this? How do I rotate only *half* of my texture? (editing the png is not an option since the texture will change.) TIA

[image: Half rotated texture]

(Download the Blender file [here](https://mega.nz/#!iYlCSQLa!igq1z05PfMcUclQR5KIRZocBzqKWrn62-v3K0uuZ1m0).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press <kbd>5 on Numpad</kbd> and Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> (User ortho and turn to back ortho) The Image will spread.

[image]

In Edit Mode Press <kbd>U</kbd> and select Project from view

Drag and make a new window as UV Image Editor

Scale UV on X and Y axis untill it match the mesh.

[image]

Comment: Great! That worked. Now WTH did I just do? :D

Comment: @atek Wow, those .gifs are a great way to answer someone's question. Nicely done.